# Overflow on multiselect box is changing document height

Tags: html, css

I have a div that scrolls in the y direction with the following css:

```
height: auto;
max-height: 300px;
overflow: auto;
```

The problem is that the text box may have hundreds of line items in it and the overflow (although not visible) is extending the overall height of the entire page and it extends beyond the footer of the page.

I essentially need to hide the overflow beyond the 300px height. But, obviously if I do overflow:hidden, I do not get a vertical scroll bar at all.

Comment: show us a full example that shows  your issue with the footer . height:auto; is maybe whats in the way

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `overflow` to `scroll`, that should do it.

```css
.overflow {
  display: block;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #AEAEAE;
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="overflow">
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>

</div>
```

This works perfectly for me.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I had tried that and it had the same result.

Comment: @bkoenig I just added code to my answer and it works perfectly for me. Make sure to click the "full page" button after clicking "Run code snippet", it's kind of hard to see in the small window on the site itself.

Comment: @s1h4d0w if you taking my answer please add my name too

Comment: Make sure to read any existing answers before commenting. My post was made before yours and you can check my edit history.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you

you can choose
display :inline block
- this is used on which the width you want to adjust like `width:100px or width:50%`

display:block;
-this is used on the width 100%

```css
.overflow {
  display: block;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="overflow">
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>

</div>
```